# symfony doctrine: find objects where one of the one-to-many-associations is like value

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have an Entity named "customer". At this entity there is an OneToMany-association to an other entity "customer-status". 
I want to get all customer-objects where ONE of the customer-status-fields is like xyz.

This is not a problem if i make a QB like this:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('s.comment', ':comment'));
$qb->setParameter('comment', "Created at %");
```

The only problem about this is, that i get all customers with the customer-statuses like the query. But only these statuses. I want ALL statuses if the like-query applies.

I have searched for this but found nothing like this. 
Anyone an idea?

Comment: Can you clarify you question? You are trying to get customer-status objects and instead you're getting customer objects? Also, where are you running this code, in the Customer repository?

Comment: I want to get customer-objects where one of the customer-status objects has a field like the query. With the attached code i get the customer-objects with especially customer-status-objects, but i want ALL customer-status-objects, only if one of the customer-status-objects has a field like the query. I run this in the customer-repo.

Answer (score 0):

After a few beers i found the anser. For the expected result i should not define the customer-status entity in the select-operation. Just select the parent-entity. 
So this:

```
$qb
    ->select(['c'])
    ->leftJoin('customer.statuses', 's')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('s.comment', ':comment'))
    ->setParameter('comment', "Created at %");
```

is the right way instead of

```
$qb
    ->select(['c', 's'])
    ->leftJoin('customer.statuses', 's')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('s.comment', ':comment'))
    ->setParameter('comment', "Created at %");
```